# Unable to define a filepath

Tags: python, file

I am trying to open a file in python. It is in a folder named `R` and the file I want to open is called `PROTO.rtf`

This is the code I have so far:

```
filepath = os.path.join(R, "PROTO.rtf")
file = open(filepath)
content = f.read()
```

This is the error it throws when I try to create my filepath:

```
NameError: name 'R' is not defined
```

Comment: `R` is a variable here, not a string. You have no `R` variable

Comment: Is ```R``` a variable? If not, then make it a string ```'R'```

Answer (score 1):

`R` would need to be a string in this case. From your code snippet, it is not defined. You'd need to include quotes around it to make it a string literal, or define it above.

Answer (score 0):

You currently have `R` being used as a variable. You didn't define a variable `R`. You want a string. If `R` is a folder in the current directory you want `filepath = os.path.join("R", "PROTO.rtf")`. If it is not in the current directory you will want `filepath = os.path.join("/full/path/to/R", "PROTO.rtf")`

[This page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-join-method/) includes a few good examples.

Answer (score 0):

Define Variable `R` before using it. Once you defined your path you can always verify you file using `os.path.isfile(file_name_with_path)`.